# Search files across folders and move recursively to new folder

Tags: mac, terminal, photos, command-line, macos

I need a way to search from a base folder, all the folders inside of that one recursively, and find all photos of `JPG` and `PNG` that were created before a certain date (01.Feb.2013) and then move them to a particular folder.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `find`:

```
touch -t 201302010000 /tmp/a
find ~/directory \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png \) -Bnewer /tmp/a \
    -exec mv {} ~/directory2 \;
```

`touch -t` normally changes only the modification and access times, but it also changes the creation time if the target time is before the original creation time or when you are creating a new file.

`-Bnewer` (for birth time / creation time) is not supported by GNU/Linux platforms which don't have metadata for the creation time.

The parentheses are needed because `-a` (and concatenating expressions without `-a`) has higher precedence than `-o`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had an answer, but I couldn't see how to string it together. This is better and succinct. I like it. Thank you very much for the explanation too!

Comment: Very clever, as always.